# Why a code snippet works fine with matplotlib 2.0.2 but raise an error with matplotlib 2.1.0

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5, python-3.6

I have the following code which works very well with matplotlib **2.0.2** (under Python **3.6.3**) but raise a type error (TypeError: 'Rectangle' object is not callable) with matplotlib **2.1.0**. 
Its aim is to interactively draw a rectangle on a graph embedded in a PyQt5 window by "press&move", rectangle which gives the new limits of the graph when user releases mouse's button 1 (i.e. zoom behaviour as Matlab do).

What am i doing wrong ?

```
# Python 3.6
...
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
...
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
...
class MplWidget(Canvas):
    zoom_in = False
    cid_zoom_P = None
    cid_zoom_R = None
    cid_zoom_M = None

    def __init__(self, parent, dpi = 100, hold = False, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(Figure())
        self.parent = parent
        self.setParent(parent)
        self.figure = Figure(dpi = dpi)
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.figure)
        self.repres = self.figure.add_subplot(111)

    ...

    def zoomManager(self, bouton_pan, bouton_tip):

        if self.zoom_in is not True:
            self.zoom_in = True
            QtWidgets.QApplication.setOverrideCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.CrossCursor))
            self.x0 = None
            self.y0 = None
            self.x1 = None
            self.y1 = None
            self.cid_zoom_P = self.mpl_connect("button_press_event", self.zoomOnPress)
            self.cid_zoom_R = self.mpl_connect("button_release_event", self.zoomOnRelease)
            self.cid_zoom_M = self.mpl_connect("motion_notify_event", self.zoomOnMotion)
        else:
            self.zoom_in = False
            QtWidgets.QApplication.restoreOverrideCursor()
            self.mpl_disconnect(self.cid_zoom_P)
            self.mpl_disconnect(self.cid_zoom_R)
            self.mpl_disconnect(self.cid_zoom_M)

    ...

    def zoomOnPress(self, event):
        if event.button == 1:
            if not bool(event.inaxes):
                return
            self.zoom_pressed = True
            self.x0 = event.xdata
            self.y0 = event.ydata
            self.rect = Rectangle((0,0), 1, 1, alpha=0.25, ls='--', lw=1, ec='k')
            self.repres.add_patch(self.rect)

    def zoomOnRelease(self, event):
        if event.button == 1:
            self.zoom_pressed = False
            self.x1 = event.xdata
            if not self.x1:
                self.x1 = self.x1_old
            else:
                self.x1_old = self.x1
            self.y1 = event.ydata
            if not self.y1:
                self.y1 = self.y1_old
            else:
                self.y1_old = self.y1
            self.rect.remove()
            self.repres.set_xlim([min(self.x1, self.x0), max(self.x1, self.x0)])
            self.repres.set_ylim([min(self.y1, self.y0), max(self.y1, self.y0)])
            self.draw()


    def zoomOnMotion(self, event):
        if self.zoom_pressed is False:
            return
        self.x1 = event.xdata
        if not self.x1:
            self.x1 = self.x1_old
        else:
            self.x1_old = self.x1
        self.y1 = event.ydata
        if not self.y1:
            self.y1 = self.y1_old
        else:
            self.y1_old = self.y1
        self.rect.set_width(self.x1 - self.x0)
        self.rect.set_height(self.y1 - self.y0)
        self.rect.set_xy((self.x0, self.y0))
        self.draw()

...
```

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] of the issue, such that people are able to reproduce it and find the error. Without a [mcve] this problem is rather hard to tackle. Also you need to provide the full error traceback, not just its last line.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest : this is a theorical question about matplotlib releases and backward compatibility. The real code a too long and complex to be post here. I already spent a lot of time to write this question...

Comment: Then the theoretical answer is: no, there is no change concerning the functionality of `Rectangle` between the two versions and the Rectangle is backwards compatible. If you are still interested in a solution to your actual problem, see above.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest : I am surprised at your answer because I see, in my case, a real difference in operation between these two versions of Matplotlib. The code partially exposed here is perfectly functional with Matplotlib 2.0.2 but is not with the version 2.1.0. In this last case, the error is generated to the call of "self.draw". I have tested a lot of variation of this statement but without success. I will try to reproduce the error under "PyPlot" to give you the example functional and reproducible requested. Thanks for your help

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I'm not saying that there could not be any change between the versions which would cause this error. What I'm saying is that there is no change in the `Rectangle`. In order to find out what causes the error, one would need a complete and verifiable example, at best, it should be minimal as well. Only then one can start debugging.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works perfertly with either 2.0.2 and 2.1.0 matplotlib versions. **But I think it is not representative of the problem that I meet**. I give it anyway because this is an example for those who would be interested in the mechanism at stake (I found no equivalent example on the net).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
import numpy as np

xdata = np.linspace(0,9*np.pi, num=301)
ydata = np.sin(xdata)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = ax.plot(xdata, ydata)

class Zoom(object):

    zoom_in = False

    def __init__(self, fig, ax):
        self.fig = fig
        self.ax = ax
        self.x0 = None
        self.y0 = None
        self.x1 = None
        self.y1 = None
        self.ax.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.on_press)
        self.ax.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('button_release_event', self.on_release)
        self.ax.figure.canvas.mpl_connect("motion_notify_event", self.on_motion)

    def on_press(self, event):
        print('press')
        if event.button == 1:
            if not bool(event.inaxes):
                return
            self.x0 = event.xdata
            self.y0 = event.ydata
            self.rect = Rectangle((0,0), 1, 1, alpha=0.25, ls='--', lw=1, ec='k')
            self.ax.add_patch(self.rect)
            self.zoom_in = True

    def on_release(self, event):
        print('release')
        if event.button == 1:
            self.x1 = event.xdata
            if not self.x1:                 # user is out of axis
                self.x1 = self.x1_old
            else:                           # user is over axis
                self.x1_old = self.x1
            self.y1 = event.ydata
            if not self.y1:
                self.y1 = self.y1_old
            else:
                self.y1_old = self.y1
            self.rect.remove()
            self.ax.set_xlim([min(self.x1, self.x0), max(self.x1, self.x0)])
            self.ax.set_ylim([min(self.y1, self.y0), max(self.y1, self.y0)])
            self.ax.figure.canvas.draw()


    def on_motion(self, event):
        if self.zoom_in is True:
            self.x1 = event.xdata
            if not self.x1:
                self.x1 = self.x1_old
            else:
                self.x1_old = self.x1
            self.y1 = event.ydata
            if not self.y1:
                self.y1 = self.y1_old
            else:
                self.y1_old = self.y1
            self.rect.set_width(self.x1 - self.x0)
            self.rect.set_height(self.y1 - self.y0)
            self.rect.set_xy((self.x0, self.y0))
            #self.draw()    # Statement that is problematic
            #plt.draw()      # Its equivalent under 'Pyplot'
            self.ax.figure.canvas.draw()


a = Zoom(fig, ax)

plt.show()
```

At this point of my research, I think the problem is not located at the patch ' Rectangle ' but rather in the following lines where ' self ' is my ' matplotlib widget ' for PyQt5 :

```
    self.cid_zoom_P = self.mpl_connect("button_press_event", self.zoomOnPress)
    self.cid_zoom_R = self.mpl_connect("button_release_event", self.zoomOnRelease)
    self.cid_zoom_M = self.mpl_connect("motion_notify_event", self.zoomOnMotion)
```

Anyway, I'm going to spend a little more time on the issue. If I can't find what I'm doing wrong, I will downgrad Matplotlib to 2.0.2.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this issue and now, i can use my zoom with PyQt5 and Matplotlib 2.1.2 (i have another problem with Matplotlib 2.2.2 for which tkagg have no cursord attribute anymore).

This is the file named **backend_qt5agg.py** which raises my error (*Rectangle is not callable*).
Line 89 and next, there was :

```
if self._bbox_queue:
    bbox_queue = self._bbox_queue
else:
    painter.eraseRect(self.rect())  # this is where a Rectangle is 'called'
    bbox_queue = [
            Bbox([[0, 0], [self.renderer.width, self.renderer.height]])]
```

I just added a 'try/except' block like this :

```
if self._bbox_queue:
    bbox_queue = self._bbox_queue
else:
    try:
        painter.eraseRect(self.rect())
    except:
        pass
    bbox_queue = [
            Bbox([[0, 0], [self.renderer.width, self.renderer.height]])]
```

and it works fine.